# How can i use tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint in Keras Tuner?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-tuner

So i want to use tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint in Keras Tuner, but The way you choose the path where to save the checkpoints, doesn't allow you to save it as a file with a certain name, a name associated to the trial and execution of that checkpoint, only associated to a epoch.

That is, if I simply put this callback in the Keras Tuner, at the moment the checkpoints save happens, in the end, I won't know how to associate the checkpoints saved to a trial and trial execution, only to epoch.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` for `Keras tuner` the same way as used in other model to save checkpoints.

After training the model with the hyperparameters obtained from the search as per [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner#train_the_model) model, you can define model checkpoints and save it as below:

```
hypermodel = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hps)

# Retrain the model
hypermodel.fit(img_train, label_train, epochs=best_epoch, validation_split=0.2)

import os
checkpoint_path = "training_1/cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
history = hypermodel.fit(img_train, label_train, epochs=5, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[cp_callback])
os.listdir(checkpoint_dir)

# Re-evaluate the model
loss, acc = hypermodel.evaluate(img_test, label_test, verbose=2)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100 * acc))

# Loads the weights
hypermodel.load_weights(checkpoint_path)

# Re-evaluate the model
loss, acc = hypermodel.evaluate(img_test, label_test, verbose=2)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100 * acc))
```

Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training) link for more inofrmation on save and load model checkpoints.

Comment: I don't understand how this could have been accepted, as it clearly does not answer the question. The question was about a step before, where we call e.g. `RandomSearch.search(...)` and not about fitting a (hyper)model with the (best) parameter set. So either the question is ill-framed or the answer has been accepted falsly. Since I have the same question as formulated above, I decidede to down-vote the answer.